# Does $o(x^n) \implies o(x^m)$ for $ 0 \le m \le n$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Let's define $o(g(x))$ as usually:

$$
\forall x \ne a.g(x) \ne 0 \\
f(x) = o(g(x)) \space \text{when} \space x \to a \implies \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
$$

If $f(x) = o(x^n)$, when $x \to 0$, for some $n \in Z^+$, then we know that $0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n}$.

I assume the following implication holds (please let me know if it does not), for each $m \in Z^+ \land m \le n$:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^m} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^m} \cdot \frac{x^n}{x^n} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} \cdot \frac{x^n}{x^m} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} \cdot x^{n-m} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} x^{n-m} = 0 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} x^{n-m} = 0 \\
\implies f(x) = o(x^m)
$$

Does it also imply that we can replace each $o(x^n)$ with its lower-order counterpart?

If we could replace it with the lower-order counterpart, it seems quite weird, because it could reduce any polynomial without a constant term to $o(1)$, so I suppose we cannot do that. Basically, I'm not sure what the difference of the two equalities is:

equation 1: $o(x^n) + o(x^m) = o(x^m)$

equation 2: $o(x^n) + x = o(x^m) + x$

Do both equations hold? Can the first equation be reduced to $o(x^n) = 0$? Why not?

Note: This is a follow up to [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439952/prove-ox2-ox2-ox3-when-x-to-0/4440044#4440044), but I made this question complete too, so it's easier to answer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Unless it has nonzero constant term, but you probably had positive-degree monomials in mind.

Comment: If a  polynomial is $o(x^{n})$ for some $n>0$ then it is $o(1)$ as $x \to 0$. Why do you think this is a  contradiction?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not claiming that that implication contradicts anything -- I hope I even provided a proof for why it holds. However, I'm new to the o-notation, and I does it even make sense to say "replace $o(x^n)$ with $o(x^m)$", or it actually only works in a sense of absorbing the two into one of the lower order (e.g. $o(x^n) + o(x^m) = o(x^m)$ vs $o(x^n) + x = o(x^m) + x$ )? The second part of my question is my main doubt there. Namely, what is the consequence of that implication?

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: $o(x^n) = 0$  no.  Equations with $o(\cdot)$ in them are not "equations" in the usual sense.  Read calculations where $o$ is used to see how they are manipulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is doubtful to write
$$
o(x^n) + o(x^m) = o(x^m)
$$
Instead I would write:
$$
\text{ As }x \to 0: \text{if } f(x) = o(x^n)\text{ and } g(x) = o(x^m),\text{ then } f(x)+g(x) = o(x^m) .
$$
This means:
$$
\text{If } \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^n} = 0\text{ and } 
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{g(x)}{x^m} = 0,\text{ then } 
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)+g(x)}{x^m} = 0 .
$$

---

Equation 2 is also doubtful; I do not know what it means.  What are you trying to say?  What would you like to do with this?

---

Some instructors of beginners write things like $f(x) \in o(x^n)$ and reason about sets.  They do this because the standard way of writing these is confusing to beginners.  But of course after the "beginner" stage, you need to be able to read and write these in the standard way.

Comment: Thank you, professor! I had in mind expression simplification, when writing the second equation, where $x$ could be any polynomial, for example. Basically, can I just replace the higher order $o$ with the lower order $o$ function? In some cases such a substitution is harder to prove than in others, and the new expression can be simpler to use, depending on the use case, so I wonder if reducing the orders can be taken as a recipe (in case $x \to 0$), or it should always be proved on case-by-case basis, because it does not always hold.

Comment: I made a concrete question here, which might clarify also what I meant in the second equation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442024/algebra-of-o-symbols.

Comment: This one is even better answer to your question, just stated as a separate question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443661/relationship-between-different-orders-of-ogx