# Relationship between different orders of $o(g(x))$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

Let's define $o(g(x))$ as usually:

$$
\forall x \ne a.g(x) \ne 0 \\
f(x) = o(g(x)) \space \text{when} \space x \to a \implies \lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0
$$

We have that $o(g(x)) = o(o(g(x)))$, or in other words:

$f(x) = o(g(x)) \iff f(x) = o(o(g(x)))$

Does this implication hold?

$h(x) = 1 + x + o(x^3) \implies h(x) = 1 + x + o(x^2)$

If it did, would then $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{o(x^2)}{o(x^3)} = 1$, because we could reduce the denominator to $o(x^2)$, because $x^3 = o(x^2) \land o(x^3) = o(o(x^2)) = o(x^2)$.

The implication the other way does not hold. Namely:

$h(x) = 1 + x + o(x^2) \;\not\! \Longrightarrow h(x) = 1 + x + o(x^3)$

Is that correct? Why the second implication does not hold?

Basically, it seems that neither of those implications hold, even though we have that equivalence between the two $o$ terms, so I'm not sure why.

Comment: If it's correct and useful yes, but it would be preferred if you can stick to the above definition of $o$, without introducing new definitions.

Comment: The first implication is true since as $x\to 0$, $$
h(x) = 1 + x + o(x^3 ) \Leftrightarrow \frac{{h(x) - 1 - x}}{{x^3 }} \to 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x}\frac{{h(x) - 1 - x}}{{x^2 }} \to 0 \Rightarrow \frac{{h(x) - 1 - x}}{{x^2 }} \to 0 \\ \Leftrightarrow h(x) = 1 + x + o(x^2 ).
$$ The opposite implication is not true. Consider for instance $h(x) = 1 + x + x^2 \sqrt {\left| x \right|}$.

Comment: Thank you Gary, can you please provide a full answer and address why extracting $\frac{1}{x}$ term in front of the limit is fine? And what about the limit I mentioned in the question which has only the $\frac{o(x^2)}{o(x^3)}$, why cannot we do the same reduction in order in the denumerator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not familiar with the convention that equalities involving symbols such as little o, big O, etc. are read from left to right and assumed to be true when read from left to right. It's usually the case that if you read them from right to left, you get something completely wrong. In other words, the equalities here are not symmetric.

As an example, writing $o(x^3)=o(x^2)$ when $x\to 0$ means that if $f(x)=o(x^3)$, then $f(x)=o(x^2)$. You can interpret this as "the class of functions which are $o(x^3)$ as $x\to 0$ is a subset of the class of functions which are $o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$." The reverse direction (i.e., $o(x^2)=o(x^3)$) is clearly wrong; just take $f(x)=x^3$, for instance.  For the same reason, we only have that $o(o(g(x))=o(g(x))$.

Also, check out [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Matters_of_notation) explanation on this matter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm not sure if it is true that equalities are not symmetric. For example the one you mentioned in the last sentence is symmetric, as far as I can tell: $f(x) = o(g(x)) \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{o(f(x))}{f(x)} = 0 \implies \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{o(o(g(x)))}{g(x)} = 0 \implies o(o(g(x))) = o(g(x)) = f(x)$. Is my proof here correct?

Comment: @S11n It's certainly possible to come up with symmetric equalities (as a trivial example, $o(x)=o(x)$). I'm talking about a widespread *convention* about how to read equalities involving little o's. As for your proof, I don't see where you've shown that $f(x)=o(o(g(x)))$ so I'd say it's not correct.

Comment: Created a separate question, to make sure I understand that better: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4444974/fx-ogx-implies-fx-oogx-and-ogx-oogx