# Algebra of o-symbols

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

In theorem $7.8$, Tom Apostol in his Calculus Vol. $1$ gave and proved the following basic rules for algebra of o-symbols

1. $o(g(x)) \pm o(g(x)) = o(g(x)) $
2. $o(cg(x)) = o(g(x)) = o(g(x)) $, if $c \ne 0$
3. $f(x) \cdot o(g(x)) = o(f(x)g(x)) $
4. $o(o(g(x))) = o(g(x)) $
5. $\frac{1}{1 + g(x)} = 1 - g(x) + o(g(x))$

Now when proving that $\tan x = x + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + o(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$, he used the following equality, only mentioning that $g(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)$ and that he is applying the 5th case of the theorem above:

$$
Equation 1: \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^2)
$$

By just applying that 5th case of the theorem, we get

$$
Equation 2: \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x^2 - o(x^3) + o(-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3))
$$

Now, I can prove that the right handside of Eq1 is equal to the right hand side of Eq2 (e.g. [using this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439952/prove-ox2-ox2-ox3-when-x-to-0/4440044#4440044)), by proving that:

1. $o(-\frac{1}{2}x^2 + o(x^3)) = o(x^2)$
2. $o(x^2) + o(x^3) = o(x^2)$

But I wonder if there is an obvious reason why the above two equalities directly follow from the Theorem $7.8$?

---

Edit, to add a suggested proof for  $o(x^2) + o(x^3) = o(x^2)$, which I hope was not even necessary, because it could be inferred trivially from the theorem $7.8$, potentially by the application of step $4$ $n-m$ times.

Let $m < n \land f(x) = o(x^m) \land g(x) = o(x^n)$.

Then we have:

$f(x) + g(x) = o(x^m) + o(x^n) = o(x^m) \cdot (1 + x^{n - m})$, because of **T7.8:3**.

\begin{equation}
\implies  \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{1 + x^{n - m}} = o(x^m)  \\
\implies 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{x^m + x^n} \\
\implies 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{x^m + x^n} \cdot (1 + 0) \\
\implies 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{x^m + x^n} \cdot (\lim_{x \to 0} 1 + \lim_{x \to 0} x^{n-m})
\end{equation}
The last equality holds because $\lim_{x \to 0} x^{n-m} = 0$. Then further we have:

\begin{equation}
\implies 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{x^m + x^n} \cdot (\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^m + x^n}{x^m}) \\
\implies 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{x^m + x^n} \cdot \frac{x^m + x^n}{x^m} \\
\implies 0 = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x) + g(x)}{x^m} \\
\implies f(x) + g(x) = o(x^m)
\end{equation}
The last equality follows by definition of little-o. By just substituting $f$ and $g$, we get $o(x^m) + o(x^n) = o(x^m)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but to prove $o(x^2) + o(x^3) = o(x^2)$, when $x \to 0$ we can take a simpler route, than what was explained in the answer (the edited part).

Namely, because of property $4$ of theorem $7.8$, we have the following:
\begin{equation}
\tag{By the definition of the $o$ notation}
x^3 = o(x^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{By substituting the $x^3$ from above}
\implies o(x^3) = o(o(x^2))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tag{By property 4 of theorem 7.8}
\implies o(x^3) = o(o(x^2)) = o(x^2) 
\end{equation}

Comment: Ok but my proof need only the definition, not the theorem.

Comment: Maybe at a higher level I will also feel confident to consider the problem solved, even when I would have to introduce a new definition, but for now I'm trying to solve the problems in the book, while staying within the provided constraints (e.g. already proved theorems and introduced definitions up to that point). Thank you for your answer, because it probably helped me get to this answer, too!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to deal with the $"o"$ notation is to write it as

$$F(x)=o(g(x)) \; (x\to 0)$$
means that

$$F(x)=g(x)\epsilon(x)$$
with
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\epsilon(x)=0$$

So, your last equality gives

$$o(x^2)+o(x^3)=$$
$$x^2\epsilon_1(x)+x^3\epsilon_2(x)=$$
$$x^2(\epsilon_1(x)+x\epsilon_2(x))=$$
$$x^2\epsilon(x)=o(x^2)$$

Comment: It seems that you just translated the problem into a different domain, but the question is still why is it obvious that this implication follows: $$\epsilon_1(x)+x\epsilon_2(x) \implies
 \epsilon(x) $$

Comment: @S11n Of which implication you are talking ?

Comment: I pressed enter for new row, and it posted the comment before it was complete. This is the implication I asked about: ϵ1(x)+xϵ2(x)⟹ϵ(x)

Comment: When x goes to zero,                   eps_1(x)+xeps_2(x)  goes to zero,      so it is an eps(x).

Comment: I don't find it obvious (nor well defined) that eps_1(x) tends to zero slower than x, when you defined also eps_1(x) to tend to 0, as x tends to 0.

Comment: by definition, $o(x^2)=x^2\epsilon_1(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to }\epsilon_1(x)=0$.

Comment: Ok, now I see you just take whole expression in the parenthesis to be another $\epsilon$, not $\epsilon_1$.

Comment: Yes. It is 6 am here, i have to go to bed.

Comment: Sounds good, have a good night. However, I am still not sure why that type of reduction can be taken for granted, as it seems quite equivalent to the original 2nd question I asked, you just use $\epsilon(x) = o(1)$. Note that the 3rd case of the mentioned theorem allows us to transform that expression into $x^2 \cdot o(1) + x^2 \cdot o(x)$

Comment: I edited my answer hoping in might clarify what level of formality I'm looking for, but I am happy to hear if any of the steps I outlined trivially holds.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below, that seems clean, without introducing any custom notation.